# Mantine DatePickerInput rendering bug

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, mantine

I'm trying to use Mantine's [DatePickerInput](https://mantine.dev/dates/date-picker-input/) in my react app but there seems to be an issue with how the component is rendered.

[Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Bv0.png)

[Current Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMFT0.png)

Library versions:

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"@mantine/core": "^7.1.7",
"@mantine/dates": "^7.1.7",
```

Implementation:

```
<DatePickerInput
  name={name}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  ref={ref}
  value={value}
  onChange={e => onChange(e ?? undefined)}
  clearable
  error={error?.message}
  {...otherProps}
/>
```

I checked to see if some styles in any of the css files went rogue but that isn't the case here. I also tried downgrading mantine to `7.1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import styles for the package like it is mentioned in the documentation – https://mantine.dev/dates/getting-started/#installation

```
import '@mantine/dates/styles.css';
```